# Show that a function is not a PRFs

Tags: proof-techniques, cryptography, randomness

I am studying cryptography and having some trouble with the PRFs
How do I show that  $f_{k}(x) =x+k^2$ mod $2^n$ is not a Psuedo Random function?  I know that I need to show that the distignuisher can tell this is not random with a better then $\frac{1}{2}$ probability but how would it do that? (I don't just want an algorithm but a means to find such an algorithm for a query attack) 
Thanks

Comment: I would assume that as long as my input is something of the form $x-k^2$ mod $2^n$ then It should be able to determine but I am shaky on the details

Comment: Did you mean to use $(x + k)^2$? $x + k^2$ is rather nonsensical considering that $k$ is just some constant key, and squaring it changes nothing about that fact.

Comment: Nope. I feel like this is super trivial. All the (incorrect) PRG does is take the input and add the key squared mod $2^n$ where n= $|k|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any known plaintext attack instantly reveals the key:
$$f_k(x) - x + 2^n \equiv k^2\mod 2^n$$

On top of that, even without knowing the key or the plaintext, here's a property that no random function should have:

$$f_k(x + 1) \equiv f_k(x) + 1 \mod 2^n$$

Comment: Perhaps another example will shed some light on this. I am a pure math guy, not a crypto guy :(
 What if $(x-k)^2 -(x+k)^2$ mod $2^n$ (I am making up obviously not true examples.

Comment: I get that I want to make an algorithm that helps a black box determine with better than 1/2 accuracy if the function is random or P-random. But what is a general way of attacking something (trivial) such as this?

Comment: @CptWobbles For really trivial things like these I generally go straight for full key recovery attacks. But showing (semi-)linear relations like I did in the second example also works.

Answer (score 0):

The way you show $f$ is not a PRF is by going back to the definition.  You say you are a pure math guy, so you should be used to this.  It's the standard dance: you look at the definition, and expand it out.

In this case, the definition of what it means for $f$ to be a PRF is: there is no adversary $A$ such that (blah).  So, the way you prove that $f$ is *not* a PRF is by demonstrating the existence of an adversary $A$ such that (blah).  How do you demonstrate that?  By exhibiting an example of such an adversary.